# crop image with react - customize react-easy-crop styling

Tags: css, reactjs, crop

I'm trying to make a very simple react component that would crop images with react-easy-crop. Apparently it is possible to customize the style of react-easy-crop module with `style` prop that takes 3 objects: `containerStyle`, `mediaStyle` and `cropAreaStyle`.

This is the default layout:

[image]

I want to expand cropArea to full width of its container and to fit media in it by height (so that we don't see the part of the original image outside of cropArea) but can't figure out how to do it. The cropAreaStyle object doesn't seem to affect width or height since it is calculated and injected in the module file (even after setting `disableAutomaticStylesInjection` to true).

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Cropper from 'react-easy-crop'
import './styles.css'

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    imageSrc:
      'https://img.huffingtonpost.com/asset/5ab4d4ac2000007d06eb2c56.jpeg?cache=sih0jwle4e&ops=1910_1000',
    crop: { x: 0, y: 0 },
    zoom: 1,
    aspect: 1 / 1,
    style: {  containerStyle: { position: "absolute", top: "0", width: "calc(100% - 2px)", height: window.innerWidth, overflow: "hidden", border: "1px solid black" }, 
              mediaStyle: { height: "100%", display: "block" }, 
              cropAreaStyle: {position: "absolute", top: "0", border: "1px solid black", width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
  }

  onCropChange = (crop) => {
    this.setState({ crop })
  }

  onCropComplete = (croppedArea, croppedAreaPixels) => {
    console.log(croppedArea, croppedAreaPixels)
  }

  onZoomChange = (zoom) => {
    this.setState({ zoom })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="crop-container">
          <Cropper
            image={this.state.imageSrc}
            crop={this.state.crop}
            zoom={this.state.zoom}
            aspect={this.state.aspect}
            onCropChange={this.onCropChange}
            onCropComplete={this.onCropComplete}
            onZoomChange={this.onZoomChange}
            style={this.state.style}
            disableAutomaticStylesInjection={true}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root')
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement)
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

The black square is cropArea that I can't resize...

I want cropArea to remain square.

Is there an easy way to do this, without changing the module file?

The solution with another module is acceptable also

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you found a solution for this yet? I am trying something similar and the solutions below aren't giving the right result.

Comment: Yes, in the end I did it using another module, react-avatar-editor https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-avatar-editor

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the object `cropAreaStyle` but it's not working, instead use the prop `cropSize` and don't pass the prop `aspect`.

In order to get the height of the media pass the prop onMediaLoaded:

```
onMediaLoad = (mediaSize) => {
    this.setState({
      cropHeight: mediaSize.height,
    });
  };
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Cropper from 'react-easy-crop';
import './style.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    imageSrc:
      'https://img.huffingtonpost.com/asset/5ab4d4ac2000007d06eb2c56.jpeg?cache=sih0jwle4e&ops=1910_1000',
    crop: { x: 0, y: 0 },
    zoom: 1,
    cropHeight: 0,
  };

  onCropChange = (crop) => {
    this.setState({ crop });
  };

  onCropComplete = (croppedArea, croppedAreaPixels) => {
    console.log(croppedArea, croppedAreaPixels);
  };

  onZoomChange = (zoom) => {
    this.setState({ zoom });
  };

  onMediaLoad = (mediaSize) => {
    this.setState({
      cropHeight: mediaSize.height,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const cropSize = {
      height: `${this.state.cropHeight}px`,
      width: '100%',
    };

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="crop-container">
          <Cropper
            image={this.state.imageSrc}
            crop={this.state.crop}
            zoom={this.state.zoom}
            onCropChange={this.onCropChange}
            onCropComplete={this.onCropComplete}
            onZoomChange={this.onZoomChange}
            onMediaLoaded={this.onMediaLoad}
            cropSize={cropSize}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4zmgud

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I need cropArea to be a square so I cannot omit the aspect parameter. I'm sorry I thought it was clear from my question since I've put aspect and wanted to have full width that it'll remain a square. I've edited my question specifying that cropArea needs to remain a square

Comment: If the cropArea becomes a square, it will be bigger than the image! in this case, you will not be able to crop a specific area in the image? and in your second image, how you will crop a specific area in the image if the square area and the image are equal in size.

Comment: As you can see in expected outcome I provided,when the cropArea is square the image should be fitted by height so you should be able to move it left or right and crop a square part.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you need is the `objectFit` property set to `vertical-cover`.

See this demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-liskov-04u7m0

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it might be a little later but what you can do is set the position relative to the cropper's parent element and then just set the width and height of the parent element that the cropper will adopt

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).